# How to count array variable if isset php

Tags: php

I want to get dynamic count variable if isset by post in array, see below code for example:

```
// Fields add dynamic by form if has input
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$mobile = $_POST['mobile'];
$departuredate = $_POST['departuredate'];
if(isset($_POST['vehicle'])){
    $vehicle = $_POST['vehicle'];
} //this field may be yes or no
$query = $_POST['query'];

// other fields

// A set of required fields
$isset_fields = array(
    $name, $email, $mobile, $departuredate, $vehicle, $query
); // how can i define here vehicle field if isset ? then count array and value
```

Comment: You want to get count of `$_POST[]` variable?

Comment: yes, each fields variable if isset

Comment: Test `count($_POST)`.

Comment: May be you are looking for this: `if(isset($_POST['vehicle'])){
    $vehicle = $_POST['vehicle']; count($_POST);
} `

Comment: mohammad ji, its count total number of POST , but i want to get variable name which is isset

Comment: @ranbir what you mean? is `$_POST['vehicle']` is array??

Comment: @ranbir `i want to get variable name which is isset`. Every post value that is in `$_POST` is setted.

Comment: @ranbir Mark one of answer to finishing this discussion.

Answer (score 1):

As `@FrayneKonok` and `@Mohammad` makes some comments. You need to use the `count` for counting the `$_POST` values and its dynamic.

```
if(isset($_POST['vehicle'])){ 
    $vehicle = $_POST['vehicle']; 
    $count = count($_POST); 
}
```

**Updates:**

If you want to get the `$_POST` keys then use `array_keys`. The array keys will gives you all the key from the POST.

Comment: You need to mention both person, I don't make it first and if you mention than it should be both.

Comment: Sorry sir and thank you for the edit and such information.

Comment: hi, i want to get name of each POST variable which is isset

Comment: The `$_POST['vehicle']` is a value so how can you count it?

Comment: i have to count total number of POST variable name in array like  
$name = $_POST['name'];  
if(isset($_POST['vehicle'])){$vehicle = $_POST['vehicle'];}  
how can i check how many variable is isset (vehicle is dynamic field)

Comment: so `$count = count($_POST); ` this is it, count the total number of posted variable.

Comment: but how can get variable name of isset post

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113246/discussion-between-ranbir-and-rivnat-nasah).

Answer (score 1):

Use `for()` to get every index of `$_POST` array. In loop you can check content of values. If content of posted value is `empty` remove it. At end you can get posted values that isn't empty.

```php
for ($i = 0; $i < count($_POST); $i++)
{
    if (empty($_POST[$i]))
        unset($_POST[$i]);   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to know how many variables are set in your `$_POST[]` super global, and I am infering you also want to know which of those values are set.

The following code will search all the values inside $_POST. It's important to understand that only values where `isset()` is true are the values that the `foreach` loop will check, because if they are not set, then the value doesn't exist.

```
$size = 0;
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)
{
    $size++;
    echo "{$key}: {$value}<br>";
}
echo "size of the array = {$size}<br>";
```

The previous code will echo out the key => value pairs in the array as well as the total size of the array.

Comment: what is the difference between `count($_POST)` and your code?

Comment: @RivnatNasah If I just wanted to get the size I would use count. Since I am infering that the OP also wants to get the $key values from the POST superglobal, I am taking advatage of the foreach loop being used to echo out the keys to also get the count manually. You could use count as well, it wouldnt make much of a difference.

Comment: @RivnatNasah the difference between my answer and your answer is our interpretation of what the OP was asking.

Comment: I know about the `array_keys` which return the key of the array. Thanks for your information.

Comment: how to validate this ?

Comment: @ranbir what do you mean by validate?

Comment: means validation if key has empty value

Comment: Oh ok, so then if you want to see if it is empty, you would use the function `empty()` like: `if(empty($_POST['vehicle'])){echo "the value is empty"}`, and if you want to put this inside the foreach loop in my previous code, you could then do: `if(empty($value)){echo "this value is empty"}`

Answer (score 0):

For clean coding use [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself) approach

```
//Define fields you want to capture here
    $fields =
    [
        'name',
        'email',
        'mobile',
        'departuredate',
        'vehicle',
        'query',
    ];


    // A set of required fields
    $isset_fields = [];

    if( !empty($_POST) )
    {
        foreach ( $fields as $field )
        {
            if( isset( $_POST[$field] ) )
            {
                $isset_fields[] = $_POST[$field];
            }
        }
    }

    //TO Get Count
    $count = count($isset_fields);
```